# Q: Create visible folder in list with SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, typescript, pnpjs

Having the following code in an application extension:

```
TypeScript
import {sp} from "@pnp/sp";

/*******************************************************************/
const shpList = sp.site.rootWeb.lists.getById(ListId);

shpList.rootFolder.folders.add('folder1');
/*******************************************************************/
```

I can create a folder inside a list. But I can only access it by typing the URL, it does not appear in the list view.

How can I make folders that are visible in the list?

Note that if I make a folder manually, it does appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like below:

```
const list = sp.web.lists.getById(ListId);
const folderName = 'My subfolder';
list.items.add({
  FileSystemObjectType: 1,
  ContentTypeId: '0x0120'
  FileLeafRef: folderName
}).then(console.log);
```

**Reference**: [Folders and sub folders inside Generic List](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/100).

Answer (score 0):

You'd need an item of type folder (i.e. set `listItemCreateInfo.UnderlyingObjectType` to [`1`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537053(v=office.14))) to do this.
Compare [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94820/c-csom-create-folders-in-lists-programmatically).

I'm not sure how to do this in `pnpjs`, though.